# How can I show my image from my code with OPENCV

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

```
include <iostream>
include <opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp>
include <opencv2\core\core.hpp>
include <opencv2\highgui\highgui.hpp>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
int main(int argc, char** argv){    
    cv::Mat src = cv::imread("lena.jpg");
    cv::Mat gray;
    cv::Mat resize;
    cv::Mat big;
    cv:: Mat enlarged;
    cv::cvtColor(src, gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);
    cv::resize(gray, resize, cv::Size(src.rows/2, src.cols/2));
    cv::resize(resize, big, cv::Size(src.rows, src.cols));
    cv::resize(enlarged, resize, cv::Size(src.rows, src.cols));
        int newsrow,newscol;

    cv::Mat clone(resize.rows, resize.cols, CV_8U);
    for(int y=0;y<resize.rows;y++){
        for(int x=0;x<resize.cols;x++){ 
        clone.at<uchar>(y,x) = resize.at<uchar>(y,x);
        }
    }

    newsrow=resize.rows*2;
    newscol=resize.cols*2;

    cv::Mat clone1(newsrow,newscol ,CV_8U);
    for(int i=0;i<newsrow;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<newscol;j++){
            clone1.at<uchar>(i,j);
        }
    }
    cv::imshow("clone", clone);
    cv::imshow("clone1",clone1);
    cv::waitKey(0);
        return 0;}
```

From my code on this line clone1 how can I show the image as clone for bigger size?
As my question is to enlarged into double size but my teacher told me that she need to enlarged by the loop into double size. So she do not need to use the library for double size.
Do not to change any loop because of my teacher need me to  enlarged image by using only this code. But you change it a little bit.
The hint: that she guide me build if loop is n/2>2;

Best Thank
Chairat (Thailand)

Answer (score 0):

You must create new Mat. And Mat.size have * operator overload. For 3 size bigger image;

```
cv::Mat BiggerImage;
cv::resize(clone, BiggerImage, clone1.size() * 3 );
cv::imshow("BiggerImage",BiggerImage);
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. But what about if loop n/2>2 that she hint me?

Comment: Then I guess I didn't understand your question well. You're trying to show clone1 bigger size? Where and how big? Why do you need a loop? Need some details.